# Docker build process and persistence of files to final image for use in container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I'm working on containerizing a somewhat complex application, and I'm running into some issues that are probably down to a lack of understanding of how Docker works and I've done a large amount of googling and reading but still  haven't seem to gotten a solution.

I'm currently using docker-compose to launch the containers, and for building using `docker-compose up --build` at build time.
I've got a .dockerignore file going to try and limit my build context as best I can or build-times can take a very long time.
my docker-compose.yml looks something like

```
services:
  base_image:
    container_name: base_image_generator
    build:
      context: .
```

My dockerfile looks something like

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as dds_install
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./rti/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0-pro-host-x64Linux.run \
        ./rti/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0-pro-target-x64Linux4gcc7.3.0.rtipkg ./
RUN chmod +x rti_connext_dds-6.1.0-pro-host-x64Linux.run \
    && ./rti_connext_dds-6.1.0-pro-host-x64Linux.run --mode unattended
RUN /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0/bin/rtipkginstall \
    -u rti_connext_dds-6.1.0-pro-target-x64Linux4gcc7.3.0.rtipkg



FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV TZ="America/Los Angeles"
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=16384
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Copy the data from the dds build
COPY --from=dds_install \
    /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0 /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0

# Copy in the license file
COPY ./rti/rti_license.dat /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.1
# Add the NDDSHOME to our path
ENV NDDSHOME /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.1.0
ENV PATH $PATH:$NDDSHOME/bin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    python3.6 \
    python3.6-venv \
    python3.6-dev


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    cmake-gui \
    curl \
    ffmpeg \
    git \
    gnupg2 \
    gnome-keyring \
    libboost-chrono-dev \
    libboost-filesystem-dev \
    libboost-program-options-dev \
    libboost-system-dev \
    libboost-thread-dev \
    libboost-timer-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    pass \
    python3-pkg-resources \
    python3-pip \
    python3-venv \
    python-is-python3 \
    tzdata \
    vim \
    wget \
    nano

RUN python3.6 -m venv /root/venv
ENV PATH="/root/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Get node 14, this is the LTS version of node and install it
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install \
    cython \
    jinja2 \
    pip-login \
    pycurl \
    setuptools \
    vcstool \
    wheel \
    xmltodict \
    gdal==2.2.3
```

I then tag the image that is generated, and move onto another docker-compose.yml that uses the generated image, and use another Dockerfile to copy source code into the Docker build context, and do a build process, and login to a private pip repo and pull down some python packages using pip.

The issue I'm running into is that my python venv isn't persisting. If I run the pip list command prior to the docker build finishing by issuing a `RUN pip list` the list that is printed is as expected. When I issue a docker-compose up, to bring a container up my app doesn't function properly though because it's missing all of the python packages that I installed, although running back using `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` shows that my virtualenv is being used (verified with a `which pip`)

Comment: Why are actually using a virtual environment if you have the isolation of the Docker container already?

Comment: Could you reduce this setup to _only_ have a Python installation, and not any of the other things (Node, the C++ Boost library, packages like `vim` and `nano` that your application will never use)?  What's the minimum possible Dockerfile that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @KlausD. Inside virtual machines or containers there are operating systems; some of them (including Ubuntu) have Python as a system programming language. Using Python virtualenvs even inside VMs/containers allows to to install/upgrade packages without risking of damaging system tools written in Python. Always using Python virtualenvs is the current best practice.

Comment: @DavidMaze I could remove nano and vim but they actually do get used somewhat in our current system setup. When we shift to production they'll be removed.  The goal of this docker build is to create a development environment for new developers so it's likely that node and the rest of the packages included will be used.

Comment: @DavidMaze if you're suggesting that I remove the installs for this question, that's a fantastic suggestion and I'll go about doing that right now.

Comment: @phd A container does not run an OS. It is an isolated environment inside the host OS. And Dockerfiles are there to have an reproducible environment, so you are not damaging any system tools, except for that image. In general if you need system tools in your container, you might have gone beyond the point where you should consider using a VM instead.

Comment: @phd I'm by no means an expert on the reasons for it. I used it because I wanted a different version of python than what was installed in the os image I chose to use. I also used the venv so I didn't get the warnings about installing certain packages as root.

Comment: @pri0ritize That' the right approach!

Comment: @KlausD. Containers certainly run OSes. I know people who run Linux inside w32 and w64 inside Linux using Docker. When I said "system tools" I meant tools of the guest OS, not host OS. Python virtualenv is a must esp. when guest OS has system tools written in Python (`apt`, `dnf`/`yum`, etc.)

Comment: No, they don't. They run processes in cgroups. And BTW "I know people..." is not a great reference.

Comment: Concur that docker doesn't run an OS, each base image may have it's own versions of software it relies on. In this case I'm using the ubuntu:20.04 image and it has Python3.8 by default. The packages that I need to pull down only function with python3.6. Removing python3.8 from the ubuntu20.04 image causes a bunch of unintended consequences (utilities missing that I'd prefer to use) and I use a venv to get around this issue.

Comment: @KlausD.  For greater reference: "I know people..." in my case meant I didn't install Docker for them but I helped to debug their Dockerfiles. I.e., I really worked with Linux-on-Windows. I don't see how you could squeeze Linux-on-Windows into broken cgroup mental model. Containers use shares of physical resources (CPU, memory, disk) but can run any guest OS and corresponding system software different from the host OS.

Comment: @pri0ritize "*Concur that docker doesn't run an OS*" Really? When your host OS is e.g., w64 and your `Dockerfile` starts with `FROM ubuntu:18` you cannot say the container runs Linux as the OS?

Comment: @phd I guess I have to find some strong words now: You have no idea how Docker works and how it is run on Windows. Please try not to transfer this to others who are seeking help! Thanks.

Comment: @KlausD. "*You have no idea how Docker works…*" Let's pretend I don't, it doesn't really matter now. My main point is not Docker, Linux or Windows. My main point is: using Python virtual environments is very much recommended even in VMs/containers. That's all.

Comment: Nope, it is not best practice for Python Docker containers.

Comment: VM's run their own host operating systems. Docker does not run it's own OS. I understand that it feels like they do, but they definitely do not. That's why they don't have the same overhead issues that VM's do. I think the venv in a docker is situational, and in my case it resolves the issues I face without using it.